# How to make atom auto-complete?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, atom-editor

In VSCode, I can auto-complete the end tag if I type the start tag in HTML.
Is there a way to replicate that in Atom?

Answer (score 0):

If you type just tag like `div`, without angle bracket (`<>`), after pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>, it will write out proper HTML code with starting and also closing tag:

```html
<div class="">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I meant was after typing the whole tag with angle brackets and pressing enter, it will auto-complete. I also discovered using tab to complete, but I have a habit to type enter, and also most of the time to write the attributes with a tag. I do not like using tab to do this, which is why I asked for an alternative to hit enter and do that.